# The constructor ReportBuilder(List<String>, Configuration) is undefined

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I'm getting an error in my Report Generator script as "The constructor ReportBuilder(List, Configuration) is undefined" on the below line of code.

```
ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
reportBuilder.generateReports();
```

Please refer my complete set of code:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

import cucumber.api.SnippetType;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;

import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;

import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser;

public class GenerateReport {   

    public static void GenerateMasterthoughtReport(){
        try{
            //String RootDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            File reportOutputDirectory = new File("target/Masterthought");
            List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            jsonFiles.add("target/cucumber.json");
            //list.add("target/cucumber2.json");    

            String jenkinsBasePath = "";
            String buildNumber = "1";
            String projectName = "cucumber-jvm";
            boolean skippedFails = true;
            boolean pendingFails = false;
            boolean undefinedFails = true;
            boolean missingFails = true;
            boolean runWithJenkins = false;
            boolean parallelTesting = false;

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, projectName);
            // optionally only if you need
            configuration.setStatusFlags(skippedFails, pendingFails, undefinedFails, missingFails);
            configuration.setParallelTesting(parallelTesting);
            configuration.setJenkinsBasePath(jenkinsBasePath);
            configuration.setRunWithJenkins(runWithJenkins);
            configuration.setBuildNumber(buildNumber);

           ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
           reportBuilder.generateReports();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions to make my script work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the latest version of `cucumber-reports` viz

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

the constructor `public ReportBuilder(List<String> jsonFiles, Configuration configuration)` exists. Please check your dependencies/CLASSPATH and make sure you are using the correct version.

Please refer [here](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/blob/cucumber-reporting-3.2.0/src/main/java/net/masterthought/cucumber/ReportBuilder.java#L58)